# how to configure sddm in kubuntu 22.04? Where is config file?

Tags: ubuntu, kde

I need to enable numlock on startup. So I'd like to put:

[General]
Numlock=on
into sddm config file, which is nowhere to be found and when creating it in some typical locations(/etc/sddm.conf, /etc/sddm.conf.d) it is ignored. Any idea what is valid location and why info mentioned in man pages does not work?

ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR:** you have to create the `/etc/sddm.conf.d` directory and conf files from scratch inside `sddm.conf.d` yourself.

I don't know why:

- It doesn't automatically create that directory anymore
- Or create an initial conf file inside it.
- Or why there's no `default.conf` in `/usr/lib/sddm/sddm.conf.d/` *(Infact there's not even an `sddm` directory inside `/usr/lib/`*

The man pages for the default ubuntu repo version of sddm even mention `/etc/sddm.conf.d` and `/etc/sddm.conf` yet they don't exist by default.

I don't know if Ubuntu moved the default configuration inside the sddm binary or something like that, but there's no sddm configuration file to be found by default, that's for sure. Look at the `apt-file` list for `sddm`

### apt-file sddm

```
sudo apt-file list sddm
sddm: /etc/dbus-1/system.d/sddm_org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.conf
sddm: /etc/init.d/sddm
sddm: /etc/pam.d/sddm
sddm: /etc/pam.d/sddm-autologin
sddm: /etc/pam.d/sddm-greeter
sddm: /etc/sddm/Xsession
sddm: /etc/sddm/wayland-session
sddm: /lib/systemd/system/sddm.service
sddm: /usr/bin/sddm
sddm: /usr/bin/sddm-greeter
sddm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/SddmComponents/Background.qml
... more qmls
sddm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/SddmComponents/qmldir
sddm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/SddmComponents/warning.png
sddm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sddm/sddm-helper
sddm: /usr/share/doc/sddm/README.Debian
sddm: /usr/share/doc/sddm/TODO.Debian
sddm: /usr/share/doc/sddm/changelog.Debian.gz
sddm: /usr/share/doc/sddm/copyright
sddm: /usr/share/man/man1/sddm-greeter.1.gz
sddm: /usr/share/man/man1/sddm.1.gz
sddm: /usr/share/man/man5/sddm-state.conf.5.gz
sddm: /usr/share/man/man5/sddm.conf.5.gz
sddm: /usr/share/sddm/faces/.face.icon
sddm: /usr/share/sddm/faces/root.face.icon
sddm: /usr/share/sddm/flags/ae.png
... more pngs
sddm: /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsession
sddm: /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup
sddm: /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xstop
sddm: /usr/share/sddm/scripts/wayland-session
sddm: /usr/share/sddm/translations/ar.qm
... more qms
```

Never the less, I created a conf file inside `/etc/sddm.conf.d/test.sddm.conf` that sets the theme to breeze

### test.sddm.conf

```
[Theme]    
Current=breeze
```

and can confirm that it forces the theme to breeze and when trying to change the theme to anything else inside System Settings, it immediately changes back until I comment out the theme or remove the file.

### System Settings > SDDM

Additionally, when I edit the SDDM settings inside **systemsettings > Login Screen (SDDM) > Behaviour** from the defaults and apply. It creates `/etc/sddm.conf.d/kde_settings.conf`.

I know you said created your conf file inside `/etc/sddm.conf.d/` and it didn't work, but this would indicate otherwise. Double check the `sddm.conf.d` folder is owned by root and conf syntax.

You could also try to change some of the default settings in systemsettings, apply and let it make the conf file for you, copy with attributes & rename, then edit the copied file with just the numlock directive you wish for.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I really don't know what(if) I did wrong, as I'm sure I test every path. But I tried to make change in sddm behavior eventhough I didn't want to change anything, that really forced generation of files, and if I put my config into them it now works. I tried to go back as well and I never  got it into non-working state again. So either kde enabled something somewhere, or I had something wrong in my initial attempts. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MartinMucha no problem. This bugged me as well. I don't know why Ubuntu felt the need to alter SDDM in such a way, it worked fine before, and now the man pages don't even match up with the expected behavior of the binary.

You can tell something is wrong when [ after making changes in systemsettings ], pressing default doesn't reset to default, it does nothing, probably because the default configuration that should exist in /usr/lib doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Also @MartinMucha you might want to put your config in separate file from kde_settings.conf. Otherwise it will get overwritten when you make a change in systemsettings. Using the same method I described with the copy w/ attributes, rename, and edit. That should make sure there's no unexpected behaviour because of permissions or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the default sddm config file and then move it to /etc/ such as:

`sddm --example-config > sddm.conf; sudo mv sddm.conf /etc/`